# Make mouse move via a virtual mouse device (none Xorg)

Tags: python-3.x, uinput

My goal is to remap a physical device (Aimtrak Lightgun) which acts like a mouse, towards different button input (the X,Y are fine).
Currently the trigger registers as a right mouse click, but I want this to become a left mouse click.

I did follow the [evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) tutorial, adjusting the "create uinput" and "injecting" parts.
There is no error, but the mouse is not moving or the button is not clicked.

So it would be fine to [grab](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-exclusive-access-to-a-device) the device and control all the input.
But I am unable to make it work.
Any other approach is also welcome.